# Community users not able to edit their questions and answers

Tags: chatter, lightning-community, chatter-groups

I have enabled chatter questions so that community users can ask questions, provide answers. But , Community users don't have the permission to edit their own existing  questions/answers. I looked into permissions for community profile, but didn't find any permission related for this.

Is it possible to provide edit access on questions and answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Chatter Questions feature, then editing feed posts (the questions) is [not permitted for Community users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_feed_post_editing.htm&type=5) with some exceptions:

> For community users, feed post editing is available only if the community was created using either Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce or the Customer Service template.

Given you meet the above, user's need the Edit Feed Post permission.